# In VBA how do I check if an OLEObject has a LinkedCell property?

Tags: vba

Is there a way to check if an OLEObject has a LinkedCell property? For example labels and buttons don't have linkedcells while others do. I am trying to write a piece of code that can replace the linkedCells by looping through all the OLEObjects in a sheet. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the standard VBA technique of catching an error to test the LinkedCell property.

```
Public Sub test()

Dim cntl As Object
On Error Resume Next

For Each cntl In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
Debug.Print cntl.Name

If IsError(cntl.LinkedCell) Then
    Debug.Print "No Linked Cell"
Else
    Debug.Print "Linked Cell"
End If

Next cntl

End Sub
```

The following is the picture of proof that it worked, on a blank Excel sheet, with four different controls.

[image]

Comment: @xiaodai, actually I tested it to make sure it would work, when I got to work later today I'll show the proof.  But really if you want help you need to give a little, like exactly how it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @xiaodai, ok, I've posted the proof.

Comment: @xiaodai, I not sure why you don't get it.  You can't just say not it doesn't like a [Monty Python skit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=teMlv3ripSM).  You need to go over __exactly__ what it is doing wrong so we can determine why.  As a programmer you need to get good at troubleshooting.  You have to fight to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Dude. I am at home. I will show you. Ok? I am genuine. I tried your solution and I found instances where it doesn't work. Trust me.

Comment: @xiaodai. You don't have to convince me, I'm sure it doesn't work for you.  I'm saying you need to be specific about what's going on to find out why.

Comment: ok this works. I was experimenting with Shapes. Essential I want to relink all the shape's objects too. I ended up writing some more advanced error trapping code to make it work. But your solution works for the original problem that I posed. Thanks. My solution is belwo

Answer (score 0):

```
    For Each tempWk In trunkWb.Sheets
            For Each tempShape In tempWk.Shapes

            Set obj = tempShape.OLEFormat.Object

            'this bit of code can be confusing but it's necessary
            On Error GoTo LinkedCellNotValid
            With Application.WorksheetFunction
                obj.LinkedCell = .Substitute(obj.LinkedCell, "[" & branchWb.Name & "]", "")

                For j = 1 To i
                    Set oldwk = trunkWb.Worksheets(sheetNames(j - 1))
                    obj.LinkedCell = .Substitute(obj.LinkedCell, "_review_" & j, oldwk.Name)
                Next j
            End With
            GoTo LinkedCellDone
LinkedCellNotValid:
            'clear the error
            Err.Clear
            Resume LinkedCellDone

LinkedCellDone:
```